# AngularJS: timeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, timeout

I'm new to AngularJS. I have this code in my controller:

```
let timeout_ = false;
let TIMELAPSE_ = 2000;
vm.setId= function (id) {
   $timeout.cancel(timeout_);
   timeout_ = $timeout(() => { SearchService.setId(id), TIMELAPSE_});
};
```

In my template I use: `ng-click="parent.setId(id)"`.
The `timeout` doesn't seem to work. Why?

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: Nope, not any error.

Comment: `setId()` is executed?

Comment: Yes, it's only the timeout that is ineffective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to parse `TIMELAPSE_` as second parameter into `$timeout` function and you will be fine. See this [runnable fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hj897at/).

```
let timeout_ = false;
let TIMELAPSE_ = 2000;
vm.setId= function (id) {
   $timeout.cancel(timeout_);
   timeout_ = $timeout(() => { SearchService.setId(id)}, TIMELAPSE_);
};
```